# How to get position of view created dynamically in main Linear Layout?

Tags: android

I am creating here a dynamic layout. I have one parent layout in which I am adding all the dynamic created views. Now on click of particular view I need position.

According to that position I have to send JsonObject which contain this view in Android. Here I am  not able to get exact position of view.

This is my code:

```
        int len = result.length();
        View addView;

        if (!(len == 0)) {

            finalResult.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                try {
                    finalResult.add(result.getJSONObject(i));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);

                if (i == 0) {

                    addView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sightseeing_firstview, null);
                    image = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.imagesightseeing_first);
                    textview = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    llfirst = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.llfirstview);
                    llayout.addView(addView);

                    String category1 = finalResult.get(i).getString("CategoryName");
                    imageurl1 = finalResult.get(i).getString("ImageUrl");

                    ((BaseActivity) SightseeingToursActivity.this).imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl1, image,
                            Common.optionsSmall);

                    textview.setText(category1);


                } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    addView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sightseeing_firstview, null);
                    images = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.imagesightseeing_first);
                    textview = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    llfirst = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.llfirstview);
                    llayout.addView(addView);
                    String category1 = finalResult.get(i).getString("CategoryName");
                    imageurlss = finalResult.get(i).getString("ImageUrl");

                    ((BaseActivity) SightseeingToursActivity.this).imageLoader.displayImage(imageurlss, images,
                            Common.optionsSmall);

                    textview.setText(category1);

                } else {
                    addView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sightseeing_secondview, null);
                    iv = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.secondimagesightseeing_second);
                    tv = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    llsecond = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.llsecondview);
                    String category2 = finalResult.get(i).getString("CategoryName");
                    imageurl2 = finalResult.get(i).getString("ImageUrl");

                    ((BaseActivity) SightseeingToursActivity.this).imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl2, iv,
                            Common.optionsSmall);
                    tv.setText(category2);


                    if (result.length() > i + 1) {
                        i++;
                        ivview = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.secondimagesightseeing_third);
                        text = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                        llthird = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.llthirdview);
                        String category3 = finalResult.get(i).getString("CategoryName");
                        imageurl3 = finalResult.get(i).getString("ImageUrl");
                        ((BaseActivity) SightseeingToursActivity.this).imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl3, ivview,
                                Common.optionsSmall);

                        text.setText(category3);


                    }
                    llayout.addView(addView);

                }

                position = llayout.indexOfChild(addView);
                addView.setTag(position);
                addView.setOnClickListener(this);

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(SightseeingToursActivity.this, "Position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    try {
        Intent in = new Intent(SightseeingToursActivity.this, sightseeing_list.class);
        in.putExtra("TourList", result.getJSONObject(position).toString());
        startActivity(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like `llayout.addView(addView);` should be outside of the last `else` block. That is, move it to immediately before `position = llayout.indexOfChild(addView);`, after the `else`'s closing bracket.

Comment: Hi Mike...i m not getting exact position yet.There are two layout.Fist one, i am adding single image and in second layout i have two image horizontally.Sequence is one image fill parent,then second layout, two image,again two image,then next one image and this is repeating.Now i want position of each images  on click.

Comment: You have written set Tag statement after adding view, so write it before adding view

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup parent;
int position;

for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    int currentViewId = parent.getChildAt(i).getId();

    if(currentViewId == wantendViewId) {
        position = i;
    }
}
```

> try this